# CSS position relative (?) and z-index

Tags: css

Greetings good people -
I need some help. I have until now buildt web-pages with floats, but now I need z-index, and therefore I need to use position

The test page is here http://www.it-stud.h...hovedp/combine/

The problem being the timelines (vertical multicoloured lines on the right), and this looks and works fine in FireFox and Opera for Mac and Pc, IE8, but scary things happens in Chrome and Safari.

It validates XHTML Transitional.

I have position inherit on some of the elements, but I have problems finding a solution.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am out to sea on this one.
All the best -

Comment: Could we have the actual URL please?

Comment: oh, dear. 
http://www.it-stud.hiof.no/~benteh/3aar/hovedp/combine/

in the meantime, it _seems_ I got it to work, but any input or feedback on different browsers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it out, by using floats and position relative. Then z-index works, and all is harmony. Glad I did not have to fiddle with absolute postioning.